# Why I get different expected_value when I include the training data in TreeExplainer?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, shap

Including the training data in SHAP TreeExplainer gives different `expected_value` in scikit-learn GBT Regressor.

**Reproducible example** (run in Google Colab):

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
import numpy as np
import shap

shap.__version__
# 0.37.0

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

gbt = GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=0)
gbt.fit(X_train, y_train)

# mean prediction:
mean_pred_gbt = np.mean(gbt.predict(X_train))
mean_pred_gbt
# -11.534353657511172

# explainer without data
gbt_explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(gbt)
gbt_explainer.expected_value
# array([-11.53435366])

np.isclose(mean_pred_gbt, gbt_explainer.expected_value)
# array([ True])

# explainer with training data
gbt_data_explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model=gbt, data=X_train) # specifying feature_perturbation does not change the result
gbt_data_explainer.expected_value
# -23.564797322079635
```

So, the expected value when including the training data `gbt_data_explainer.expected_value` is quite different from the one calculated without supplying the data (`gbt_explainer.expected_value`).

Both approaches are additive and consistent when used with the (obviously different) respective `shap_values`:

```py
np.abs(gbt_explainer.expected_value + gbt_explainer.shap_values(X_train).sum(1) - gbt.predict(X_train)).max() < 1e-4
# True

np.abs(gbt_data_explainer.expected_value + gbt_data_explainer.shap_values(X_train).sum(1) - gbt.predict(X_train)).max() < 1e-4
# True
```

but I wonder why they do not provide the same `expected_value`, and why `gbt_data_explainer.expected_value` is so different from the mean value of predictions.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Part of an explanation: trying to extract explanations from `gbt_data_explainer` fails with a helpful message. Running `gbt_explainer.model.fully_defined_weighting, gbt_data_explainer.model.fully_defined_weighting` gives `True, False`: shap thinks that `X_train` doesn't reach every leaf of every tree.

Comment: Relevant bit of the code: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/f459bdf4c574f739886818a6ba84327e3af163ad/shap/explainers/_tree.py#L1339
I'm not sure why shap would get different predictions using its C code (https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/f459bdf4c574f739886818a6ba84327e3af163ad/shap/tree_shap.h#L234); sklearn splits at midpoints (between feature values), so I wouldn't expect rounding errors to be the culprit.

Comment: @BenReiniger I am not following - `X_train` is the very same set used for fitting the model. Feel free to post even a partial answer, if you have one

Comment: My understanding [background] `data` is a helper to reduce run time. Sampling perturbations from background data rests on the assumption of feature independence, which is not the case for this particular dataset, so sampling produces unrealistic combinations of features. See [here](https://edden-gerber.github.io/shapley-part-1/) [here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/955) [here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/1098) [here](https://github.com/christophM/interpretable-ml-book/issues/142) and [here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/882)

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov so you say it is due to the non-independence of features in the specific dataset?

Comment: This is my best bet based on half an hour research. There are still many issues with this explanation: why TreeExplainer is insensitive to `feature_perturbation` param? Is it a bug? Is TreeExplainer really an exact method of shap value estimations? In case of background data how many samples one needs to get exact results?

Comment: Getting there: `gbt_explainer.data.shape` is just `(100, 10)`...but I can't find where in the code it's doing that (subsampling?).  So then when it does the previously linked step "Re-compute the number of samples that pass through each node if we are given data", it doesn't have the whole set and fails to populate all the leaves as noted before.  See also the explainers' `.model.node_sample_weight` lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently `shap` subsets to 100 rows when `data` is passed, then runs those rows through the trees to reset the sample counts for each node.  So the `-23.5...` being reported is the average model output for those 100 rows.

The `data` is passed to an `Independent` masker, which does the subsampling:
https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/v0.37.0/shap/explainers/_tree.py#L94
https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/v0.37.0/shap/explainers/_explainer.py#L68
https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/v0.37.0/shap/maskers/_tabular.py#L216

Running

```py
from shap import maskers

another_gbt_explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(
    gbt,
    data=maskers.Independent(X_train, max_samples=800),
    feature_perturbation="tree_path_dependent"
)
another_gbt_explainer.expected_value
```

gets back to

```
-11.534353657511172
```

Answer (score 2):

Though @Ben did a great job in digging out how the `data` gets passed through `Independent` masker, his answer does not show exactly (1) how base values are calculated and where do we get the different base value from and (2) how to choose/lower the `max_samples` param

**Where the different value comes from**

The masker object has a `data` attribute that holds data after masking process. To get the value showed in `gbt_explainer.expected_value`:

```py
from shap.maskers import Independent
gbt = GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=0)

# mean prediction:
mean_pred_gbt = np.mean(gbt.predict(X_train))
mean_pred_gbt
# -11.534353657511172

# explainer without data
gbt_explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(gbt)
gbt_explainer.expected_value
# array([-11.53435366])

gbt_explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(gbt, Independent(X_train,100))
gbt_explainer.expected_value
# -23.56479732207963
```

one would need to do:

```py
masker = Independent(X_train,100)
gbt.predict(masker.data).mean()
# -23.56479732207963
```

**What about choosing `max_samples`?**

Setting `max_samples` to the original dataset length seem to work with other explainers too:

```py
import sklearn
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import shap
from shap.maskers import Independent
from scipy.special import logit, expit

corpus,y = shap.datasets.imdb()
corpus_train, corpus_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(corpus, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=10)
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus_train)

model = sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression(penalty="l2", C=0.1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

explainer = shap.Explainer(model
                           ,masker = Independent(X_train,100)
                           ,feature_names=vectorizer.get_feature_names()
                          )
explainer.expected_value
# -0.18417413671991964
```

This value comes from:

```py
masker=Independent(X_train,100)
logit(model.predict_proba(masker.data.mean(0).reshape(1,-1))[...,1])
# array([-0.18417414])
```

`max_samples=100` seem to be a bit off for a `true` base_value (just feeding feature means):

```py
logit(model.predict_proba(X_train.mean(0).reshape(1,-1))[:,1])
array([-0.02938039])
```

By increasing `max_samples` one might get reasonably close to `true` baseline, while keeping num of samples low:

```py
masker = Independent(X_train,1000)
logit(model.predict_proba(masker.data.mean(0).reshape(1,-1))[:,1])
# -0.05957302658674238
```

So, to get base value for an explainer of interest (1) pass `explainer.data` (or `masker.data`) through your model and (2) choose `max_samples` so that base_value on sampled data is close enough to the true base value. You may also try to observe if the values and order of shap importances converge.

Some people may notice that to get to the base values sometimes we average feature inputs (`LogisticRegression`) and sometimes outputs (`GBT`)