# SHAP Explainer gives different results for the same data

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap

I am working on explainability of my LGBM model using SHAP values.
I define my explainer as following:

```py
explainerModel = shap.Explainer(my_model.predict_proba, X)
```

where `my_model` is my trained LGBM binary classification model, and `X` is a dataset based on which the model was created.

When I fetch the SHAP values more than once for the same sample data (e.g. first row of `X` - `X.iloc[:, 0:1]`) using

```py
# First try
explainerModel(X.iloc[:, 0:1]).values

> Gender                         0.023290 
> age                            0.023388 
> marital_status                 0.028853
> InvestmentIncome               0.105607

# Second try: the same code
explainerModel(X.iloc[:, 0:1]).values
> Gender                         0.016755 
> age                            0.021644 
> marital_status                 0.051004
> InvestmentIncome               0.091735
```

it gives me slightly different results. They sum up to the same values of course (+0.181138), yet the SHAP values individually can be different from each other by a fraction up to 10% (e.g. SHAP values for the same variable: Gender - 0.023290 for first calculation, 0.016755 for second).

How to make it so that they are fixed for the same data? Should I fix something in the explainer?

Comment: Possibly the same underlying issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64828997/10495893)?

Comment: If I understand correctly, that posts says that if creating one `shap.Explainer` twice, it would give two different results. My question is about different results, but from the same object. I am not redefining my `explainerModel`, I just use it twice on the same data.

Comment: can a person, who is closing the question all the time, might give an explanation for it and maybe suggestion to what is unclear?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but a minimal example would be really helpful here. In particular, what kind of model are you using? Can you provide the data, or recreate the issue on open data (like one of sklearn's datasets)?

Comment: Thanks @BenReiniger. I am using LGBM, but I can't provide the data and I'm not sure if that would help. I will try to recreate the problem on the open data.

Comment: I found this to be the case as well - specifically when I was using an explainer with a model with the .predict_proba() method. I think this is partially the result of Explainer defaulting to the 'permutation' method, which may only be approximate. I was able to get the same results if I: 1) explicitly set the seed for the explainer (seed argument) and 2) Re-instantiated that same method before I explained the same dataset again. I will post a more complete solution if I come to a deeper understanding of what is going on.